# Yii - How to make text field validation for numbers on keypress

Tags: javascript, validation, yii

I'm new to Yii framework and I use the below code to validate the textfield only for numbers. But, this fails to work in IE 9 and below browser but works in IE 10 and 11 and other browsers.

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    console.log("charcode",charCode);
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

How can I solve this problem for all browsers.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the built in Yii validation for your form?

Comment: @JoeMiller I don't know I added the rules for integer only in model class...but the data is extracted from xml file. Hence, it seems to be not working

Answer (score 1):

I think its better that you should define validation in your model class, then it will work on all your browser.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
           array('fieldName', 'required'),
           array('fieldName', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        );
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Thanks.